# strange encoded mp3 file in xml need help to get it back

Tags: c#, xml, base64

i have an XML file which holds alot of data.

For the moment i can read out every data in c# except a mp3 file which is hold as an base64 string in a child.elemt named Data with commentary line: "4 bytes float array converted to base64".

I am very new to c# and before just a beginner in php/java, so be indulgent.

I  have attached the base64 string in a text file and the original mp3, maybe it helps. 
Can you tell me how i can convert this back ? I already tryd to get single bytes out of the array to a stream and write it back as mp3 file, but atleast its 4 times bigger and absolute not near the same file and just holds in crap.

https://www.file-upload.net/download-12719496/base64string.rar.html

edit: 
After the Help of L.B, i got this, thank you.

```
var mp3base64string =  Convert.FromBase64String(child.Element("Data").Value);
   using(FileStream file = File.Create(mp3datafilename)) {
    using(BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(file)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mp3base64string.Length; i += 4) {

      writer.Write((byte)(967.644334 f * BitConverter.ToSingle(mp3base64string, i)));
      }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works and the output is exactly the same as original mp3, but don't ask how I got that magic number :) (Does author of xml think it is some kind of encryption/obfuscation?)

```
var buf = Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(@"base64string.txt"));

int count = 0;
var buf2 = buf.GroupBy(x => count++ / 4)
            .Select(g => (byte)(967.644334f * BitConverter.ToSingle(g.ToArray(), 0)))
            .ToArray();

File.WriteAllBytes(@"base64string.mp3", buf2);
```

*PS:  A non-linq version will be faster....*

Comment: Thank you @L.B ! This works for all strings correctly, shit i really want to ask :D